# Groovy not running scripts presumably because of permissions

Tags: java, exception, groovy, file-permissions, noclassdeffounderror

The change occurred after upgrading Debian

Ahead all descriptions:

- the root user has no problems; Groovy is doing as expected
- the normal user
  -- can run java programs and grails projects
  -- but groovy would not run a script any more?!

Extract from printenv:

```
GRAILS_HOME=/usr/local/lib/grails
GROOVY_HOME=/usr/local/lib/groovy
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

All needed is in the PATH and the file permissions in JAVA_HOME and GROOVY_HOME are OK:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-post-Debian-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-post-Debian-1, mixed mode, sharing)

$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 3.0.9 JVM: 11.0.13 Vendor: Debian OS: Linux
```

But no script will be run any more for the normal user:

```
groovy -e='println "OK"' ## or
groovy my_script.groovy

Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class groovyx.javafx.extension.NumberExtension due to missing dependency javafx/beans/value/ObservableNumberValue
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class groovyx.javafx.extension.NumberExtension due to missing dependency javafx/beans/value/ObservableNumberValue
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

The same error will be thrown in the groovyConsole for the simple println "OK"

groovysh is more terrifying:

```
$groovysh

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:111)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class groovyx.javafx.extension.NumberExtension due to missing dependency javafx/beans/value/ObservableNumberValue
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.Java8.configureClassNode(Java8.java:460)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:273)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:395)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.AbstractExtensionMethodCache.scan(AbstractExtensionMethodCache.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.AbstractExtensionMethodCache.getMethods(AbstractExtensionMethodCache.java:97)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.AbstractExtensionMethodCache.getMethodsFromClassLoader(AbstractExtensionMethodCache.java:73)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.AbstractExtensionMethodCache.get(AbstractExtensionMethodCache.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroCallTransformingVisitor.findMacroMethods(MacroCallTransformingVisitor.java:119)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroCallTransformingVisitor.visitMethodCallExpression(MacroCallTransformingVisitor.java:90)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GroovyCodeVisitor.lambda$visitListOfExpressions$0(GroovyCodeVisitor.java:202)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GroovyCodeVisitor.visitListOfExpressions(GroovyCodeVisitor.java:202)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitTupleExpression(CodeVisitorSupport.java:249)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitArgumentlistExpression(CodeVisitorSupport.java:367)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression.visit(ArgumentListExpression.java:73)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitMethodCallExpression(CodeVisitorSupport.java:186)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroCallTransformingVisitor.visitMethodCallExpression(MacroCallTransformingVisitor.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBinaryExpression(CodeVisitorSupport.java:202)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitDeclarationExpression(CodeVisitorSupport.java:335)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitDeclarationExpression(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.DeclarationExpression.visit(DeclarationExpression.java:89)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:117)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:200)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:86)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:164)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.MethodCallTransformation.visit(MethodCallTransformation.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor.lambda$addPhaseOperationsForGlobalTransforms$4(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:337)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ISourceUnitOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:901)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:671)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:635)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:389)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$3(GroovyClassLoader.java:332)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:330)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:526)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:538)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:426)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:461)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:436)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.util.PackageHelperImpl.getPackagesAndClassesFromJigsaw(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:153)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.util.PackageHelperImpl.getPackages(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:127)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.util.PackageHelperImpl.initializePackages(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:64)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.util.PackageHelperImpl.<init>(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:53)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:72)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:277)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Groovysh.<init>(Groovysh.groovy:113)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Groovysh.<init>(Groovysh.groovy:102)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Groovysh.<init>(Groovysh.groovy:142)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:72)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:286)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Main.<init>(Main.groovy:66)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:72)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:286)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Main.main(Main.groovy:155)
        ... 6 more
```

Thank you for any idea!

Comment: Have you tried installing javafx? E.g. `openjfx`  comes up in `apt search`...

Comment: Yes, I did it now, but the problem persists. And remember: ROOT could run groovy scripts also without openjfx...

Comment: I install groovy and grails always by hand from the ZIPs in /usr/local/lib/. which groovysh is /usr/local/lib/groovy/bin//groovysh for all users inclusive root. It's in the PATH

Comment: Root might just see a different groovy version.  E.g. for me in Debian testing, groovy shows up as 2.4 - so you having 3.0 and the /usr/local location looks like youi have installed it yourself. Also there should be no need for javafx for groovysh/groovy, which is plain CLI. What does `which groovysh` give you for root and $USER? Do you remember adding groovyfx stuff to your local install?

Comment: Then the environment or your user-setup triggers this. An fresh SDKMAN installation of groovy 3.0.9 needs no groovyfx (for me). To trigger the error you are seeing i have to run a groovy script, that grabs groovyfx.

Comment: No, my groovy script contains only println "OK". It runs well for ROOT and fails for USER. That's why I suppose a permission problem. The groovyfx error is only the written hiccup  of not being able to get to something. Given that java and grails are running well, what needs groovy more than they on is own?

Comment: I don't understand the last statement.  Is the error when you run `groovy -e='println "OK"'` `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class groovyx.javafx.extension.NumberExtension due to missing dependency javafx/beans/value/ObservableNumberValue` or not? If that is the case, then my guess is, that something contaminates your installation. And root is not contaminated (different env, no $DISPLAY set, ...)

Comment: Yes, this is the error; same as trying to run println "OK" in groovyConsole. I purged and reinstalled java. I deleted and reinstalled the groovy ZIPs. If ENV contamination: why should java and grails run as expected. Meanwhile I upgraded at home to the same Debian Testing (bookworm) and I don't have the issue  ?! Wondering...

Comment: I went back to the office computer trough VPN ;) and I set the $DISPLAY... but no good.

Comment: Neither java, grails, or groovy use groovfx by default.  So there is no surprise, that those things work - the surprise is, that groovy is not working with that error. So I'd expect env, config-file, ... - and that's the reason why root works. The only other explanation would be, that root actually has javafx (e.g. by using another java installation).

Answer (score 1):

**Many thanks to cfrick** pointing to groovyfx. - I found the culprit.

Even if I didn't call groovyfx at all, **I had a groovyfx-8.0.0.jar in my ~/.groovy/lib/** directory - from an old home carried over to a newer computer.

Why this didn't give errors in Debian Bullseye but does in Debian Bookworm remains a mystery; I didn't have openjfx installed then until now - and now it does not make any positive difference.

The only recent reference to groovyfx not working I found here: http://foro.chuidiang.org/groovy/groovyfx/ and it is true, that the code from http://groovyfx.org/docs/index.html#_hello_groovyfx_your_first_groovyfx_program does work with Oracle-Java 8 but does not work with open-jdk+openjfx ?!

But this is another story altogether.

Comment: I dont have the details, but AFAIR javafx was part of jdk8 and it got separated somewhere between jdk11. And who knows what changed over that period (e.g. packages might got renamed, APIs changed, ...). So that groovyfx version might just be to old for openjfx.

Comment: It still remains strange to me, that groovy first tries to resolve all possible dependencies found in its CLASSPATH ~/.groovy/lib before simply println an "OK" on the console, not needing any of the jars storred there

Comment: Without knowing the details, an explanation would be: the lib dir there is part of the classpath and the groovyfx lib contains things groovy must know before running other code (e.g. AST transformations, macros, ...)